# Java string comparison, printing two different string inputs into alphabetical order

Tags: java, printing, string-comparison, alphabetical

We are learning `compareTo()` method and `equals()` method, but I am unsure how to properly print the words in alphabetical order.

I have 2 Strings:

```
String firstString;
String secondString;
```

that are assigned values (elsewhere).

I have tried:

```
System.out.println(firstString.CompareToIgnoreCase(secondString));
```

but am only getting integers in my output as opposed to full words.

Comment: [String.compareToIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) is designed to return an integer telling you the result of the comparison.  It's up to you to then write code to do something with that knowledge.

Comment: Hint for all new / learner Java programmers: if a method returns an unexpected (to you!) result or throws an unexpected (to you!) exception ... **check the documentation**.

Answer (score 1):

As this is homework, I'll only address your stumbling block.

As per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)), `compareToIgnoreCase()` (and more generally, [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))) returns an integer, either negative, zero or positive, depending on whether the first parameter's order is less than, the same or greater respectively than the second parameter.

You'll need to check the result of `compareToIgnoreCase()`, *then* print based on that, for example:

```
if (firstString.compareToIgnoreCase(secondString) > 0) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those taking the same class, this solves the requirements for the question:

```
  if (firstString.compareTo(secondString) < 0) {
     System.out.println(firstString + " " + secondString);
  }
        
  else {
     System.out.println(secondString + " " + firstString);
  }
```